# FLUTTER: Hacer un ListView i ListTitle o expansion Title App de la sigueinte manera

Tags: listview, flutter

Necesito hacer una lista desplegable de manera que muestre 5 titulos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que al presionar el botón que esta en la parte inferior suba una lista de elementos que también pueda seleccionar
Como puedo hacer para lograr esto

Comment: Te refieres a algo como esto? https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/expansion-tile-sample

Comment: Si, pero en vez de una lista que sea en sentido hacia arriba desde un boton como se muestra en la imagen

Comment: Ahh entonces estás buscando un modal bottom sheet checa esto https://flutterdoc.com/bottom-sheets-in-flutter-ec05c90453e7

Comment: Muchas Gracias.